# Converting date format with sed

Tags: date, sed, format

I have a question how to convert date from i.e. 'Jun 14 2012 5:00PM' to '2012-06-14' using sed? So ommiting '5:00PM' as well.
I'm trying something like `s/(...)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/$2.$1.$3/` but can't get it right.
Thanks!

Comment: The non-trivial part is converting `Jun` to `06`. I can't help thinking `sed` is not the right tool for that.

Comment: do you have to use sed? The GNU date cmd can convert this, or awk programming lang is a better choice. Search here for other date conversion solutions. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You really do not need sed to do it - you need date:

```
$ date --date='Jun 14 2012 5:00PM' '+%Y-%m-%d'
2012-06-14
```

In this command, I am asking date to convert the date `'Jun 14 2012 5:00PM'` to the format composed by the four-digits year (`%Y`) followed by an hyphen and the two-digits month (`%m`) followed by another hyphen and the two-digit day (`%d`).

Now, some notes about your sed command:

Sed uses an specific, somewhat limited regular expression syntax. One of the differences is that the parenthesis groups should be preceded by backslashes for effectively grouping. If there is no backslash, the parenthesis is considered a literal parenthesis char. This is exactly the contrary of the regex in other languages, I know, but it is how it work. So, instead of

```
s/(...)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/$2.$1.$3/
```

you  should have

```
s/\(...\)\(\d\d\)\(\d\d\d\d\)/$2.$1.$3/
```

Also, there is no `\d` wildcard in sed. Instead, you should use `[[:digit:]]`:

```
s/\(...\)\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\)/$2.$1.$3/
```

or, better yet:

```
s/\(...\)\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)/$2.$1.$3/
```

Last but not least, the reference to the matched groups is not marked by `$`, but instead by a backslash:

```
    s/\(...\)\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)/\2.\1.\3/
```

(Oh, uh, ok, you could use [extended regexes with GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps), too, but what would be the fun?)

Anyway, this will not match your date either - I just mentioned the syntax errors, there are some semantic errors too (for example, your date is separated by spaces that are not present in the regex). Nonetheless, this is no problem because date can do it better.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what the date will be se the first option won't work :)

Comment: @irek I don't understand. You do not know the format of the date? It is not possible to post a date in the format you will get?

Comment: It's like this: I get the date in format: Jun 16 2012 5:00AM and desired format is: 2012-06-16

Comment: this date is just an example :)

Comment: I'm trying something like this: s/\([a-zA-Z]\{3\}\) \([0-9]\{2\}\) \([0-9]\{4\}\) \([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([A-Z]\{2\}\)/\3-\1-\2 \4:\5:\6/ and it's almost correct (except 'Jun') ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Jun 14 2012 5:00PM" |
sed 's/$/Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/;s/\(...\) \(..\) \(....\).*\1\(..\).*/\3-\2-\4/'
2012-14-06
```

Add a lookup and match using back references.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
echo "Jun 21 2011 5:00PM" | 
awk '{"date \"+%Y/%m/%d\" -d \""$1" "$2" "$3" \"" | getline var; print var}'
```

#### Test:

```
$ echo "Jun 21 2011 5:00PM" | 
awk '{"gdate \"+%Y/%m/%d\" -d \""$1" "$2" "$3" \"" | getline var; print var}'
2011/06/21
$
```